# Trying to come up with regex for US states (abbreviation and full name mixed all together)

Tags: c#, regex

I guys. I'm trying to come up with a regex (C#) for eg: FL or Florida. I have `[A-Z]{2}` but some results are coming back empty because the patterns are mixed, full names are being used also. Thanks.

Comment: Why regex? If your aim is validating some state value, won't it be easier compare with C# HashTable (constant time lookup)?

Comment: I'm doing 'data scraping'. I use a software that based on the url grabs the data and convert it into xml. I just paste the XPath in it and the software does the trick. There are states that comes,eg: MO but also Missouri.

Comment: Regular expressions are powerful, but not always the best tool for the task. This is one of those cases where a regex is *not* the right method.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart +1 for best tools. In the immortal words of Larry Wall, `Doing linear scans over an associative array is like trying to club someone to death with a loaded Uzi.`.

Comment: Your question as nothing todo with C# ! It is only a Regex question !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following regex will match what you are after:

```
/AL|Alabama|AK|Alaska|AZ|Arizona|AR|Arkansas|CA|California|CO|Colorado|CT|Connecticut|DE|Delaware|FL|Florida|GA|Georgia|HI|Hawaii|ID|Idaho|IL|Illinois|IN|Indiana|IA|Iowa|KS|Kansas|KY|Kentucky|LA|Louisiana|ME|Maine|MD|Maryland|MA|Massachusetts|MI|Michigan|MN|Minnesota|MS|Mississippi|MO|Missouri|MT|Montana|NE|Nebraska|NV|Nevada|NH|New Hampshire|NJ|New Jersey|NM|New Mexico|NY|New York|NC|North Carolina|ND|North Dakota|OH|Ohio|OK|Oklahoma|OR|Oregon|PA|Pennsylvania|RI|Rhode Island|SC|South Carolina|SD|South Dakota|TN|Tennessee|TX|Texas|UT|Utah|VT|Vermont|VA|Virginia|WA|Washington|WV|West Virginia|WI|Wisconsin|WY|Wyoming/
```

I would not recommend it (per the comments above), but it will do the trick. It contains the names of all 50 states as well as their abbreviations, separated by `or`. Thus it will match any of these. You might consider adding word boundaries etc...

It is starting to look a lot like a lookup, isn't it?