# Location name inconsistency in database

Tags: sql, database

I have a column of state names which has a mixture of abbreviations and full names of each of the states. I need to run a query in a way where I can standardize the format. Either "full names" or just the abbreviations.

Comment: Probably a good task for Regex. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587805/trying-to-come-up-with-regex-for-us-states-abbreviation-and-full-name-mixed-all

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like function. The statement will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE STATE_COLUMN LIKE 'STATE NAME' OR LIKE 'STATE ABBREVIATIONS'
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Why `LIKE` without wildcards? What's wrong with `=`?

Comment: String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. Double quotes are for identifiers.

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect and doesn't seem to do much that is useful.  How could it be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building a temp table, like this:

```
State, Abbreviation
Alabama, AL
Alaska, AK
Arizona, AZ
```

Then join the temp table to your table t:

```
SELECT temp.state
FROM t
INNER JOIN temp ON t.state IN (temp.state, temp.abbreviation)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this method is very useful. The only problem is there are many states. And of various countries. Is there any way I can tackle this issue?

Comment: Skip the UNION, do `... INNER JOIN temp ON t.state IN (temp.state, temp.abbreviation)` instead.

Comment: @jarlh. What do you think of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901791/is-having-an-or-in-an-inner-join-condition-a-bad-idea

Comment: @kbball, probably interesting for MS SQL Server users. But we have no dbms here, and no table or index definitions.

Comment: @jarlh, I agree. Update made - I wasn't sure on best practice here but your solution looks cleaner to me.